# How do I show things directly to the screen in Android?

Tags: android

I'm new to android and I was wandering is there a way to show a stream or a pic to the screen directly even without the manifest?

Or how do I load resources files without using the manifest on the Android platform?

Comment: you cannot unless you hack into dalvikVM.

Comment: so for every resource file I want to load I need to add a reference to the XML manifest, and a constant to the R class?

Comment: What about the: getClass().getResourceAsStream("") &&       getClass().getResource("").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wandering is there a way to show a stream or a pic to the screen directly even without the manifest?

The manifest is not directly involved with showing "a stream or a pic to the screen".

> Or how do I load resources files without using the manifest on the Android platform?

The manifest is not directly involved with loading resource files.

Comment: +1 Actually the only really involved part is the R class which holds all references to the resources.